# convert eregi to php 5.3

Tags: php, deprecated, eregi

Does anyone know how I would convert the following code to php 5.3?

```
if (eregi('^(' . $value . ')(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$', $this->browser_languages[$i]) && isset($this->catalog_languages[$key])) {
```

Thanks

-James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ereg functions became deprecated, replace them with the PCRE functions

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php

**Edit :**

To change from eregi to preg_match, you need to choose a character that will server as a delimiter (I often choose #) and add after the delimiter an i flag (wich means case insensitive).

You example :

```
if (eregi('^(' . $value . ')(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$', $this->browser_languages[$i])
    && isset($this->catalog_languages[$key])) {}
```

Will become :

```
if (preg_match('#^(' . $value . ')(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$#i', $this->browser_languages[$i]) 
    && isset($this->catalog_languages[$key])) {}
```

This is the minimum you need (note that you may need to use `preg_quote()` for the `$value` but I didn't add it to note complicate things for now)

another note is that if you want to convert ereg (not eregi), you don't need to add the i flag.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still absolutely no wiser as to what to convert it to as I don't really understand what the eregi is actually doing.

Comment: eregi is a function for matching regular expressions, if you don't know what regular expressions are, you can read a little about them here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: sorry for my curt response, but my situation is i've just moved a clients website over to a new server and it's bringing up that error on the home page. I've got to fix it as fast as I can before he notices. I'm not sure I deserve to be modded down as a result.

Comment: See my edited answer (I hope you can spot the difference)

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thanks very much. I tried changing it, but based on other answers on SO i was putting a slash in there, not a hash, plus i missed out the i at the end. I fully get the difference.

You've saved my bacon and I'll now know the answer for next time!

Comment: you can put a slash instead of hash, but if the regular expression contains a slash too, you will have to escape it with an anti-slash, a hash is less frequently used so that's why I use it (note that you can use any character not only slashes and hashes as a delimiter)

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match()` with the `i (PCRE_CASELESS)` modifier is the suggested alternative.

Comment: I'm still no wiser on exactly what code to change it to.